# Unable to creating subnet with python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

The custom VPC is already in place. I am using the following request body parameters to create a Subnet:

```
subnetwork_body = {
    "privateIpGoogleAccess": 'false',
    "ipCidrRange": "192.168.0.0/24",
    "region": "us-central1",
    "name": "subnet-aa",
    "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/networks/yourvpc"
}
```

When using this body with python I am getting the following error:

```
recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/abc/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/network/createvpc.py", line 59, in <module>
    pprint(createsubnet(compute, project, networkmode))
  File "C:/Users/abc/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/network/createvpc.py", line 47, in createsubnet
    return compute.subnetworks().insert(
  File "C:\Users\abc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\abc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 907, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/regions/custom/subnetworks?alt=json returned "Permission denied on 'locations/custom' (or it may not exist).">
```

But when I use the "try this API" in the below link, it is working perfectly.

```
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/subnetworks/insert
```

Below is the request body values I am using with "try this API"

```
{
  "privateIpGoogleAccess": false,
  "ipCidrRange": "192.168.0.0/24",
  "region": "us-central1",
  "name": "subnet-aa",
  "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/networks/yourvpc"
}
```

There are two difference between the above two steps:

1. The Python code is using service account with owner role and the value of "privateIPGoogleAccess" is in single quote.
2. In the API call I am using the user account with owner role and the value of "privateIPGoogleAccess" is without any quote.

I can understand 403 error meaning but not sure why there is a permission issue.

I tried but I am not able to figure out the issue. Request if someone can help to correct the mistake.

Thanks

Edit:
Below is the screenshot which shows that the API call runs successfully.

[image]

Comment: Double check project id "myproject"

Comment: I was just trying not to publish my original project id but missed to replace the one you found.

Comment: Can you share how you call the API with the already shared body?

Comment: I am looking at this error "403 when requesting ...... 
 myproject/regions/custom/subnetworks?alt=json returned "Permission denied on 'locations/custom' (or it may not exist).">". After regions/<region> i suspect we need a region like us-central1. I would check in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code, creating a subnet worked for me

---

```
from pprint import pprint
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
# Project ID for this request.
project = 'xxxxx'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.
# Name of the region scoping this request.
region = 'us-central1'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.
subnetwork_body = {
    "privateIpGoogleAccess": "false",
    "ipCidrRange": "192.168.0.0/24",
    "region": "us-central1",
    "name": "subnet-aaaa",
    "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxxxx/global/networks/new-terraform-network"
}
request = service.subnetworks().insert(project=project, region=region, body=subnetwork_body)
response = request.execute()
# TODO: Change code below to process the `response` dict:
pprint(response)
```

Comment: Thanks for spending your valuable time on my post. I have added the screenshot to my post for your reference.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce that custom error you got, however the above worked for me. Only change i made is the project ID and the network name change. Both "false" and 'false' also worked.

Comment: Dany L: Sorry, I think I wasted your valuable time. The error was due to my typo in the code. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

By mistake I was passing the value of networkmode instead of region to compute.subnetworks().insert(). and networkmode was having  a value "custom"

```
pprint(createsubnet(compute, project, networkmode))
```

Hence I was getting the error:

```
returned "Permission denied on 'locations/custom' (or it may not exist)
```